# segmentation fault

Tags: c

Tengo un problema cuando trato de asignar un caracter a mi puntero 'next', me lanza un error de segmentacion. Con el debugger eh visto que *next apunta a un caracter, lo unico que quiero hacer es pisar ese caracter con un espacion en blanco (' '). No entiendo el por que del error, ya que next es inicializado con mi puntero s1, la cual no viene NULL, pero ademas eh corroborado que no se haya desbordado de la cadena.

```
int deleteChar(char *s1,const char *s2)
{
  char *first = s1,
       *last = s1,
       *next = s1;
  int accumulator = 0;

while(*next)
{
    while(isWhite(*next) && *next)
        next ++;
    while(*next && !isWhite(*next))
    {
        if(isCharacter(*next, s2))
        {
            *next = ' '; //error de segmentacio
            accumulator ++;
        }
        next ++;
    }
    while(last < next)
    {
        if(*last != ' ')
        {
            *first = *last;
            first ++;
        }
        last ++;
    }
    *first = ' ';
    first ++;
}
first --;
*first = '\0';

    return accumulator;
  }

int isCharacter(const char c, const char *s)
{
  while(c != *s && *s)
    s ++;

  return c == *s ? 1 : 0;
}

#define isWhite(X) ((X) == ' ' || (X) == '\t')

int main()
{
char *s1 = {"algo que se me ocurrió"},
     *s2 = {"aeiou"};
int cant;
printf("Prueba eliminar caraacter\n");

puts(s1);
puts(s2);
cant = deleteChar(s1,s2);
printf("La cadena modificada es: %s",s1);
printf("Cantidad de caracteres eliminados: %d",cant);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la primera línea de `main`

```
char *s1 = {"algo que se me ocurrió"},
```

La variable `s1` es un puntero a un literal de cadena de caracteres. Intentar modificarlo es comportamiento indefinido.

Para tener una cadena modificable debes declararlo así :

```
char s1[] = {"algo que se me ocurrió"},
```

Ahora `s1` es un array de caracteres y lo puedes modificar. Y, aunque ahora `s1` no es un puntero sí se puede usar en todo lugar(*) en que se necesite un puntero a carácter pues se evalua como un puntero al primer carácter de esta cadena modificable.

(*) en realidad no, por ejemplo no puedes tomar la dirección de s1; esto también sería comportamiento indefinido `char**p = &s1;*p = 'a';` si `s1` es un array. Pero esto sería tema para otra pregunta.

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que se intenta hacer, pero cuando programo yo haría esto: `char* s1 = "algo que se me ocurrió"`, es decir, sin los corchetes.

Comment: @ArtEze puedes hacer eso sin problemas siempre que **no quieras modificar** la cadena apuntada por `s1`. Sin los corchetes `s1` es un puntero que apunta a una cadena de caracteres que no se debe modificar. En algunos sistemas, como Linux, estos dato se colocan en una zona de memoria protegida contra escritura e intentar modificarla provoca un error. Con corchetes significa algo muy diferente, entonces `s1` es un array cuya memoria está ubicada en la pila y al inicio de la función en que está ubicada el compilador genera código para copiar esa cadena a esa zona de la pila, que es modificable.